# When Numberformat is set to "MM/YY" the result on german computers is "MM.YY"

Tags: excel, vba, number-formatting

I want to create a number format for the x axis in an excel chart.

If I set it manually as "MM/JJ" I get correct dates printed as "04/23".
If I set the numberformat using vba

```
Dim cht As Chart
Set cht = ws.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers).Chart
cht.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "MM/YY"
```

The result is "MM.YY"

The language of the computer is german.

Answer (score 5):

Write a date in a cell like 03.08.2023 (german)
Format it as MM/JJ
You will see 08/23 like you wish
Goto the Immediate Window (Direktfenster) (STRG +G) in VBA Editor and write

```
?ActiveCell.NumberFormat
```

the result is
mm\/yy

It is always helpful approach

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if "MM.YY" means that you get the letters M and Y or that you get the wrong separator. Assuming the latter, add a backslash before the slash, like this:

```
cht.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "MM\/YY"
```

The slash means "use the date separator from my locale". By prefixing it with a backslash you escape that.